# Javascript - Evaluate result in form with if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to evaluate a result using an if statement on the below form. When the 2nd result is divided by the 1st result an average percentage is yielded. If that percentage is greater than or equal to 55 the result should return "Pass" else it should be "Fail". Not sure where the bug is with my IF statement.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".input").keyup(function() {
    var val1 = +$(".value1").val();
    var val2 = +$(".value2").val();
    $("#result").val("$"+(val1 / val2).toFixed(2));
    var val3 = +$(".value3").val();
    var val4 = +$(".value4").val();
    $("#result2").val("$"+(val3/val4).toFixed(2));
    $("#result3").val(((val3/val4)/(val1/val2)*100).toFixed(2) + "%");
            var result = $("#result2").val()/$("#result").val();
            if(result >= 55){
      $("#TestResult").val((result * 100).toFixed(2) + "%" + "Pass");
    } else {
      $("#TestResult").val("FAIL");
    }

});
});

</script>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Non-taxable benefits paid to Highly Compensated EE's:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="input value1">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Number of Highly Compensated Employees:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="input value2">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Average Benefits paid to Highly Compensated EE's:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="result">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Non-taxable benefits paid to Non-Highly Compensated EE's:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="input value3">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Number of Non-Highly Compensated Employees included*:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="input value4">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Average Benefits paid to Non-Highly Compensated EE's:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="result2">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Average Benefit Percentage Ratio:</td>
    <td>
       <input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="result3">
    </td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Result:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text"  id="TestResult" style='overflow:hidden; border:0px solid #000000; width:80%'>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like homework. Anyway, your values from your inputs (`$('#result2').val()` etc) look like "$15.055", which will fail because it'll see the "$" sign and assume it's 0.

You can either save the value before you prepend the "$" then use that, or just slice it:

```
+( $("#result2").val().slice(1) ) / +( $("#result").val().slice(1) )
```

Answer (score 0):

In all the others, you used number coercion, but you didn't this time.

```
var result = (+$("#result2").val())/(+$("#result").val());
```

Comment: It has a $ sign on the front, added by the previous code

Answer (score 0):

Change the below code 
 var result = $("#result2").val()/$("#result").val();

into

var result = $("#result2").val()/$("#result").val();

result  = parseInt(result);

Comment: `parseInt` will lose the decimal precision, and the values have a $ sign on the front anyway, from the previous lines of code